# Compilation error in Scala Play conf\routes file

Tags: scala, playframework

What would cause this Scala Play compilation error?

```
Compilation error
HTTP Verb (GET, POST, ...), include (->) or comment (#) expected
In C:\time-enough-at-last\conf\routes at line 1.

1 # Routes

2 # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
3 # ~~~~
4
5 # Home page
6 GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
```

(Note that the line numbers you see above are not actually in the file.)

One of the things it's expecting is a comment.  Well, it's getting a comment, isn't it?

```
# Routes
```

Comment: Your file looks good to me. Just a quick guess: this could be an encoding issue. Is your `routes` file UTF-8 with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? If so, please save it without the BOM and try again.

Comment: The encoding is ISO-8859-1.  Is that okay?  What should it be?

Comment: Sorry, it was encoded in UTF-8.  I saved it without BOM and now it works!  Thanks!!